# How to use EventEmitter in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I created a small Express server in Node.js with a singular route. When an HTTP request is used to GET '/get-jobs' I want to emit an event that communicates said event to another file that send s an axios request to console.log the data on a page URL I specify. However, for some reason my EventEmitter is not correctly listening on the axios file. How can I fix this?

Here is my entry point:

```
import express from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

import EventEmitter from './EventEmitter.js';

const app = express();
dotenv.config({ path: './config.env' });

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/get-jobs', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Route was hit');
  EventEmitter.emit('getJobs', req);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${process.env.PORT}...`);
});
```

Here is my axios job file that is currently not listening:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import EventEmitter from './EventEmitter.js';

EventEmitter.on('getJobs', () => {
    await main();
  console.log('Test');
});

async function main() {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      'https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/?q=javascript&where=Saint-Louis__2C-MO&stpage=1&page=4'
    );

    console.log(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

And here is my event emitter file:

```
import EventEmitter from 'events';

export default new EventEmitter();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, because you didn't include the (axios-containing) file in your app. The file that listens to events hasn't started yet. So, try to import the file in your running app. And don't forget to add *async* keyword in your case.

```
EventEmitter.on('getJobs', async () => { await ...
```

Remember that we listen to events before we publish them.
Hope this answer helps.